# Get NetworkInfo return isconnectedtoprovisioningnetwork()

Tags: android, wifi

Hello my app is connected to a WIFI without access to internet. How can I get the return of isconnectedtoprovisioningnetwork()? I want to get if it's true or false and relate it in my code.

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED && info[i] != null && info[i].isAvailable() && info[i].isConnected() )

                    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will tell you either you are connected to WIFI or not.

```
public boolean isConnection(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi!=null && mWifi.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Do not forget to add permission.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I dont think this code will tell you if internet is actually passing through your wifi. One case for example is if you are behind a captive portal, you will still get true for isConnected().

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null

    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()

    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```